# Can I change the width size in Xcode from compact to any without destroying my project?

Tags: xcode, ios8, autolayout

I mistakenly developed my app with width set to compact and height to any.  Now, I'd like to change the width to any, but all but one of my UI elements disappear from view, even with constraints all blue.  Is there a way to do this without needing to re drag and drop the UI elements and connecting?

Comment: You should in general use code to place your UI elements, then such stuff will not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CGPointMake function to reposition things. Get an image, button or other element into place and do this (in your .m file corresponding to the element's view controller of course):

```
 yourElement.center = CGPointMake(X, Y)
```